# How to make the app start a new activity at only the specified time not starting from it

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager

I want my app to start activity "playing", when user is in activity "start" only at the specified time, let's say 17:00:00, and, if user is in activity"start" at any other time after 17:00:00, the activity "playing" doesn't start. I used this code :

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(2019, 2, 25, 17, 00,00);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Start.this, Playing.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(Start.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    ((AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE)).set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

The problem is, it takes me to "playing" activity at any time after 17:00:00.
What should I change to restrict it to only the exact specified time?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of starting the activity, you can start a `Service` from the alarm manager. And in your `Service`, check if your Activity `Start` is in foreground and it is exactly 17:00:00. And if the conditions meet, only then start your activity from the service.

Following is the code to check if any activity is in foreground.

```
public boolean isForeground(String myPackage) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> runningTaskInfo = manager.getRunningTasks(1); 
    String className = runningTaskInfo.get(0).topActivity.componentInfo.getClassName();
    return className.equals(YourActivityClassName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just put the code inside a condition that the current time is less than the wanted time.